# Remove space after command

Tags: macros, spacing, programming

To simplify some text I created some commands. One command has no arguments. It uses math mode but is used inside normal text. I would like to remove any trailing space between the command and following text. This will allow me to simply the call such as `\cmd sometext` instead of `{\cmd}sometext`. Is there any way to create a negative space?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If your command is truly a single macro without arguments, i.e. `\cmd`, then it gobbles spaces written after it anyway.  To ensure that any command will absorb following spaces, just make the last thing to appear in it `\ignorespaces`, which causes TeX to consciously discard space characters until the first non-space appears.

By the way: `{\cmd}sometext` does not do what you think, if part of the action of `\cmd` is to make definitions of some kind.  Those definitions will be discarded inside the group created by `{...}` unless you make them global.  The way to have two items bump up against each other but be parsed separately is to write `\cmd{}sometext`.  However, as I said, `\cmd` itself will eat spaces no matter how you define it.

Comment: I've should have known this. I've been using latex for a few years and it just didn't occur to me that it automatically deleted spaced. (I guess because 99% of the stuff I do is in math mode or has no arugmentless commands)

Comment: I believe that you ment to say "outside" instead of "inside" in the sentence "Those definitions will be discarded...". Right?

Comment: @gebruiker Yes.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I found that I had left an extra trailing space inside the brackets of a new command. `\newcommand{\fullname}{Tom Anderson }` ended up putting a space between my name and the comma when I used `\fullname, \date` (i.e. it outputted "Tom Anderson , 2017"). I knew that the spaces should be gobbled so checked the command definition to find my error.

Answer (score 9):

That is the default behavior as the output of `\foo bar` shows below (the first line). To introduce negative horizontal space you could use `\kern`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\foo}{foo}%
\newcommand*{\fooWithKern}{foo\kern-1ex}%
\begin{document}
\foo bar

\fooWithKern bar
\end{document}
```